# How can I add Digit places to my results?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am pretty new to VB, so please be nice.  I have a small speedtest click event in a utility I am creating.  When I get the output to text the Kb/sec only shows the first two digits.  It always seems to drop the 0.  So for instance if the speed was 210 kb/sec it will show in the output as \t21 kb/sec.  I can't tell if I am doing the math wrong or if I have inadvertently restricted the output to only two digits.

```
Dim starttime As Integer = Environment.TickCount
        'Download the source to the temp path
        wclient.DownloadFile("http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test10.zip", "C:\temp\speedtest.txt")
        Dim endtime As Integer = Environment.TickCount
        Dim secs As Integer = Math.Floor(endtime - starttime) / 1000
        Dim secs2 As Double = Math.Round(secs, 0)
        Dim kbsec As Integer = Math.Round(1024 / secs)
        Dim SPEED_NAME As String = "C:\temp\logs\speedtest.txt"
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(SPEED_NAME, False)
        objWriter.WriteLine("Begin Speed Test")
        objWriter.WriteLine("10mb download: \t{0} secs ({1} secs)", secs2, secs)
        objWriter.WriteLine("Download rate: \t{0} kb/sec", kbsec)
        objWriter.WriteLine("End Speed Test")
        objWriter.Close()
        MsgBox("Text written to file")
        MsgBox("Cleaning up... (deleting downloaded file)")
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code in debug mode?  I think you'd find the problem if you checked the values as they were calculated.  You're not downloading a 1K file, right, it's 10M?

Comment: @Beth That is correct I am downloading a 10Mb file.  The code was originally written for a 1k file but I had to up the size to get a better test.

Comment: then you need to up the value in your math an equivalent amount

Comment: @Beth I see so up the math number to 10000000 from 1000

Comment: Also note that you are changing the extension from .zip -> .txt. I'm not sure what the zip contains or what you are doing with the file once it is downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a breakpoint and check the values of secs and secs2. It's possibly that you're expecting kbits per second but getting kbytes per second, using the file size of 1024 in bytes. Either way, it might prevent future errors to get the file size in bytes with file.length and use that in the calculations.

Note: secs could conceivably be zero sometime, which would cause a divide by zero in the assignment to kbsec.